# Show that $|x-y|<0.5|y| \implies |x|>0.5|y|$

Tags: vector-spaces

How to show that $|x-y|<0.5|y| \implies |x|>0.5|y|$, where $|...|$ is a norm and $x,y$ are vectors of a vector space over field $R$?

Comment: Have you tried drawing what this means in the plane? That should give you some insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the triangle inequality,

$$|y| = |y - x + x| \le |y - x| + |x| < 0.5|y| + |x|,$$

which implies

$$|x| > |y| - 0.5|y| = 0.5|y|.$$

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**

By the triangle inequality we have

$$|y|-|x|\le  |x-y|$$